# toggle allow edit on form

Tags: settings, axapta, aot

I unfortunatelly clicked on the checkbox to modify content at user setting of the Invent Journal Transfer form.
[image]
Now the form is not active and due to that I can not open user setting to take steps back.
I have tried to find in properties of the form in AOT where is setup to not allowed to edit the form but i haven't find.

I have also tried to find somenthing in users group security but also nothing.

Can somebody help please?

Thanks in advance

Vladimir.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the following information: What version of AX are you using? Has the form been customized? Have you tried resetting the form, which would remove any personalization changes made? You can also remove usage data.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to reset the usage data or a subset of usage data for your user. Check out http://daxdude.blogspot.com/2013/11/dynamics-ax-2012-resetclear-your-users.html

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand u trying to edit item inventsite from journal lines.
If its posted basicly u cannot edit. also inventdimensions work with DimGroupId u can simply just go inventtable and check dimgroupid is it allowed the inventsite.
Form looks like this > http://www.dynamicsaxtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/InventoryDimensions.png